# Access violation on passing byte[] from c# to plain c dll

Tags: c#, c, dll, unity-game-engine, access-violation

I'm trying to use the SOIL library for my Unity3d project. I slightly modified the code to compile it to a DLL.
I have a C-function with signature:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
unsigned int SOIL_load_OGL_texture_from_memory
    (
        const unsigned char *const buffer,
        int buffer_length,
        int force_channels,
        unsigned int reuse_texture_ID,
        unsigned int flags
    );
```

I declared it in my c# script:

```
  [DllImport("SOIL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  private static extern uint SOIL_load_OGL_texture_from_memory(
    System.IntPtr buffer,
    int buffer_length,
    int force_channels,
    uint reuse_texture_ID,
    uint flags);
```

Try to call:

```
GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
System.IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
uint id = SOIL_load_OGL_texture_from_memory(pointer, bytes.Length, 3, 0, 0);
pinnedArray.Free();
```

And get an Access Violation. So I try to pass *IntPtr* as *const unsigned char **. Maybe I need to use something different from GCHandle?

**Edit:** It crash the whole Unity 3D in play mode: Access Violation at MSVCR120.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake absolutely unrelated to passing byte array. The problem was that I started Unity without -force-opengl (Direct3D by default I think) and SOIL works with OpenGL only.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Marshal.Copy(Byte[], Int32, IntPtr, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146625(v=vs.100).ASPX) and passing the pointer to your C call

Comment: I tried `Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pointer, bytes.Length)`, but result is the same.

Comment: Not sure, but [the double const declaration](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/general/article.php/c6967/Constant-Pointers-and-Pointers-to-Constants.htm) may be what's causing the problem

Comment: I made a simple wrapper inside SOIL with no const's, but no luck.

Comment: could you post the exception message and the stack trace?

Comment: I figuired out that it was completely unrelated to passing byte array (check my answer). Thank you very much for your help!